# Free up memory on Android when push Back Button

Tags: android, memory, back-button

I have 2 activities, `Activity1` and `Activity2`. In `Activity1` I have a button to go to `Activity2`.

Activity2 has a lot of Edittext and other Views.

When I start the app, the memory of the process is 10mb. If I click on the button and `Activity2` is loaded, my memory's process is about 59mb.

The issue is, in `Activity2`, if I push Back Button, I return to `Activity1` and my memory's process is about 59mb, and I don't need this information about `Activity2`.

Now, If I click again the button, I have an `OutOfMemory`.

How can I force to free up the memory when I push Back Button?

I try to call `finish()` and `System.gc()` but It doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: show us the relevant source code of your activity

Answer (score 1):

try this one....
first close your activity...
use following code...

```
public class ur_clss extends Activity {
private ur_class c1;
//ur content here
     @Override
     public void onBackPressed () {
               c1.finishActivity(0);
     }
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Override `onBackPressed` in `Activity2` so that `finish()` is called. Android will destroy all resources.

Comment: He shouldn't have to do this at all.  If the Activity is popped from the backstack, the resources will be cleaned up anyway.  There's something else wrong.

Comment: Have a reference to itself? Something like this?
    Activity2 = Activity2.this;

Answer (score 0):

You need to **override** the BackButton and free up the memory when it is pressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
Activity.finish() // the activity that you want to terminate
}
```

Or, there is another way to do it.  When you start the new activity, the old activity goes onPause(). You could try calling `finish()` in the `onPause()` of the old activity.

Comment: Activity2 is inside a TabActivity, I can't call finish() because every time that I push the tab it will recreate.

Comment: Yeah, so every time it is recreated, it would take up the space only once. That way I do not think that you would run into OutOfMemory.

Comment: It's not recommended because now the loading process is about 7 seconds, and when I change the tab and I return, it's loaded and I've not to wait again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of the code:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    // Global variables
    private CarregaOperacions carrega_operacions;
    private TableLayout taula;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Some code of UI

    // Show a ProgressBar
    loadProgress();
    carrega_operacions = new CarregaOperacions(Activity2.this);
    carrega_operacions.execute(null);

}

    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {

        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

static class CarregaOperacions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    WeakReference<Activity2> context;
    Activity2 act;

    public CarregaOperacions(Activity2 activity) {
        context = new WeakReference<Activity2>(activity);
        act = context.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            act.carregaOperacions();
        return null;
    }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

         ArrayList<LinearLayout> llista = act.getLlistaFiles();
         for (int i = 0; i < llista.size(); i++ ) {
             act.getTable().addView(llista.get(i));

         }

         act.getScroll().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         act.treuProgres();
     }
 }
```

With this code, I explain a bit:

- The real case is, Activity1 calls a TabActivity, that has the Activity2. Activity2 loads a lot of registers, and I do this asynchronously. I Override onKeyDown in Activity2 and on the TabActivity, but it seems that only is onKeyDown's Activity2 executed.